# Change form color background on submit click using java

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form

[image]

What i need to to do is to change the color of the form's background to either red if it's wrong or green if it's right, when the "check answer" is clicked.

this is what i have so far:

Javascript

```
function chagecolor()
        {
            var changec = document.getElementById("answer")
            if (changec == "BURJ KHALIFA")
            {
                changec.style.backgroundColor = '#F40320';

            }
            
            else
            {
                changec.style.backgroundColor = '#03C13D';

            }
```

HTML

```
            <hr>
            What's the tallest building in the world in 2022? <!--BURJ KHALIFA-->
            <form >
                <input style="text-transform: uppercase;" type="text" id="answer" name="answer">
                <input onclick="changecolor()" id="turnon" type="submit" value="Check Answer">
```

Can someone point me on the right direction
Thanks

Comment: What's going wrong with the solution you've attempted?

Comment: @mykaf Nothing happens no color

Comment: Do you see the error in your console? `changecolor()` is not defined.

Comment: Also, please log `changec` to the console - that variable is the entire HTML element, whereas I believe you want to use its value in the comparison.

Comment: update your condition like this
`if (changec.value == "BURJ KHALIFA")`

Comment: Isn't `function chagecolor()` missing an `n`?

Comment: @j08691 your comment also helped me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
        var changec = document.getElementById("answer")
        if (changec == "BURJ KHALIFA")
```

document.getElementById will return an `Element` or null/undefined. Neither of these will ever be equal to a String

Instead, you want

```
        if (changec.value == "BURJ KHALIFA")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are calling the wrong method on the input.

Secondly your if statement in the method should check for changec.value and not only changec.

I hope this can guide you in the right direction :D

Answer (score 1):

Update your condition as below

```
if (changec.value == "BURJ KHALIFA")
```